# Page layout of parts included by the \include command

Tags: sectioning, formatting, include

It is customary in big works like books or user manuals to split content in several separate files and `\include` them in the main document: usually each file contains a chapter, an appendix or more generally a unit of text which not nested in any of the remaining others. I tried to extend the use since, writing a user manual of a complex system, I have several parts which remains unchanged even for different systems and thus different manuals: therefore I tried and succeed in including single paragraphs or groups of such sections/subsections, which are naturally nested inside a single chapter, in the sense that the index numbering so generated is more than correct. However, as Mittelbach and Gossens say at page 19 of "*The LaTeX Companion*" (2nd ed.),

> Note that each document part loaded via `\include` starts on a new page and finishes by calling `\clearpage`; thus, floats contained therein will not move outside the pages produced by this part. So natural candidates for `\include` are whole chapters of a book but not necessarily small fractions of text.

I would like to know if there is a way to inhibit this behavior, namely to avoid that chosen parts included with `\include` will start on a new page.

Comment: No. In any case, you can't nest `\include`. Just use `\input` for the paragraphs and stuff and `\include` only for the whole chapters referenced from the top-level master file. `\input` is just like including the file contents here and is perfect for this.

Comment: @cfr. Thank you very much. Apart from your comment, I found also very useful the link to the answered question "[When should I use \input vs. \include?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include)" you, Torbjørn T., Kurt, Troy, samcarter added. Best,